# list.writerow() is writing into alternate rows in excel csv format

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I'm trying to import data from Yahoo and write it into a csv file in a different format to what I download, but whenever i do this, it prints the data into every alternate cell in excel. I'm confused as i can't find anyone else who had this. My code for the write is this:

```
with open(file, "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerow(fields)
        for word in datee:
            writer.writerow([word])
```

and the output is this:
[image]

```
Timestamp   Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close   Volume  Split
                        
02-06-2022                          
                            
01-06-2022                          
                            
31-05-2022                          
                            
27-05-2022                          
                            
26-05-2022                          
                            
25-05-2022                          
                            
24-05-2022
```

Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: post the content of the csv

Comment: I did it's the picture below. The excel file.

Comment: the actual file. in text

Comment: The whole few thousand rows or just a part of it

Comment: the post the first few lines

Comment: It only let's me add a picture when i try to copy

Comment: Post it to Gist / Pastebin or other online paster

Comment: using `for word in datee:` you insert every word in different line, is this what you intent to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Use emacs, or another tool that can reveal detailed file contents,
to find what kind of line terminators ATHE.csv has.

From the double spacing, my guess is it has CRLFs.
And then upon input, Excel interprets each CR (ascii 13) as end-of-line, and the subsequent LF (ascii 10) as **also** being an end-of-line.
So you get two, where just one was intended.
You'd be better off with just LF at the end of each line.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) suggest passing a `newline` option:

```
open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='')
```

cf the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for `open()`.

---

Carefully examine `datee`,
to verify it doesn't have extra whitespace or empty elements.